# How to use norms to prove non-UFD?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, unique-factorization-domains

I was asked to provide an example of an integral domain in which the uniqueness provision of "unique factorization" fails. So my example is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$. My reasoning is that $6$ can be factored as $2*3$ and $(1 + \sqrt{-5})(1 + \sqrt{5})$, but I am having trouble to prove these are two different factorization. I took norm of each factor and say that

$$N(1 - \sqrt{-5}) = N(1 + \sqrt{-5}) = 6$$
while
$$N(2) = 4, N(3) = 9$$. Since the norms of $2$ and $3$ do not divide the ones coming from the other factorizations, these are two different factorizations. Am I right? Thanks!

Comment: This has been discussed here *many* times before. Please search before asking.

Comment: @BillDubuque I looked it up, and I found a lot of related questions (they even proved these elements are irreducible), but not exactly this. Specifically, I want to know if this reasoning is valid. So if you have a direct link to "the many times before", that would be amazing.

Comment: You wouldn't say that $4\cdot9$ and $6\cdot6$ are different factorizations of $36$ in the ring $\Bbb{Z}$, right? The argument must include irreducibility of those numbers.